# How to run multiple async method in sequence then execute normal function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have 3 async functions and a synchronous one. How to run these methods serially?

```
async function Method1(obj) {
    let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/';
    let obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    console.log('seq 1');
}

async function Method2(obj) {
    let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/';
    let obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    console.log('seq 2');
}

async function Method3(obj) {
    let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/';
    let obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    console.log('seq 3');
}

function Method4 ()
{
    //Some Non-Async Code
    console.log('seq 4');
}
```

It should give:

```
seq 1
seq 2
seq 3
seq 4
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap it in another `async` function and use `await` to call these other `async` functions.

Example using anonymous wrapper:

```js
(async () => {
    await Method1(foo);
    await Method2(foo);
    await Method3(foo);
    Method4();
})();
```

Comment: Happens to this too, it ran in sequence but it didnot wait for Methods to finish. What I wanted is first finish Method1 then execute Method2 and so on...

Comment: Then you do something funny. It does wait for `Method1` to finish and calls `Method2` after that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a problem:

You've redeclared variable `obj` in `Method1`, `Method2` and `Method3`.

Since you don't use the argument at all, just remove it, like this:

```js
async function Method1() {
    let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/';
    let obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    console.log('seq 1');
}

async function Method2() {
    let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/';
    let obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    console.log('seq 2');
}

async function Method3() {
    let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/';
    let obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    console.log('seq 3');
}

function Method4 ()
{
    //Some Non-Async Code
    console.log('seq 4');
}
```

Another problem is that `https://www.googleapis.com` doesn't return a valid JSON (it returns the string `Not Found`), so all `fetch` requests will fail. For testing, I've replaced all URLs with [JSONPlaceholder's](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/).

And now, to the question:

You can build an asynchronous promise-chainer function:

```js
async function executeSequence(seq){
  for(const fn of seq) await fn();
}

executeSequence([
  Method1,
  Method2,
  Method3,
  Method4
])
```

This will work with synchronous functions as well (`await` doesn't mind).

Working example:

```js
async function Method1() {
    let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
    let obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    console.log('seq 1');
}

async function Method2() {
    let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
    let obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    console.log('seq 2');
}

async function Method3() {
    let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
    let obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    console.log('seq 3');
}

function Method4 ()
{
    //Some Non-Async Code
    console.log('seq 4');
}

async function executeSequence(seq){
  for(const fn of seq) await fn();
}

executeSequence([
  Method1,
  Method2,
  Method3,
  Method4
]).catch(console.error)
```

Comment: It ran in sequence but it didnot wait for Methods to finish. What I wanted is first finish Method1 then execute Method2 and so on...

Comment: How is that more readable than putting `await` in front of each method? Keep it simple.

Comment: @JamshaidAlam The problem was with your functions. I've edited my post, check it now

Comment: If it's less readable and more verbose, then what's the point?

Comment: That it can be reused. But did you notice my phrasing: "*You **can** build an asynchronous promise-chainer function*". The OP can choose your solution if they want, that's another version.

Comment: There's a name for that: overengineering. Try avoiding it, you're not becoming a better programmer by abstracting everything. There is literally zero reasons to do it like you did. Especially that it's also wrong, as you ignored OP's parameters.